# Can you express the idea of "he just doesn't get it" with the verb "rentrer"?

Tags: expressions

> On arrête pas de lui dire que ..., mais **ça rentre pas**.

I want to say "he just doesn't get it" colloquially, but I wonder if this phrasing gets the job done right without an addtional phrase "ça rentre pas (dans ...)"?

I assume that dictionaries do not cover this particular "rentrer" usage.

Comment: [The TLFi entry for "rentrer"](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rentrer) does include an "Empl. abs." example, albeit positive & sort of passive, of "rentrait" by itself seeming to mean "something {le métier] finally 'being got/understood': − "Au fig., fam. Rentrer dans la tête. Être su, être admis. ....
♦ Empl. abs. Ainsi, approximativement et peu à peu, le métier «rentrait», comme on dit (Fombeure,Soldat, 1935, p. 20)"

Comment: @PapaPoule What's your take on some variants of this expression? E.g.: "***ça refuse de me rentrer dans le crâne !***" or "***ça ne veut pas me rentrer dans le crâne !***" I wonder if you can also drop the "dans ..." part in these two instances?

Comment: The context would probably make it clear enough without the "dans ..." part, but be careful not to create (unless that's your intention) a "double-entendre" from the "c) Pénétrer avec son sexe" sense of "rentrer [dedans]"! For what it's worth, my favorite ways of saying "doesn't get it" come from variations of "n'en piger que dalle."

Comment: J'ai aussi entendu "il imprime pas" sans trop savoir si c'est plutôt un jargon de techniciens ou informaticiens ou plus communément admis.

Answer (score 3):

> On arrête pas de lui dire que ..., mais **ça rentre pas.**

is perfectly idiomatic, albeit colloquial.

As to what it does not penetrate, here are some directions:

- *ça rentre pas dans sa caboche*
- *impossible de lui rentrer ça dans le crâne*

You can even convey the same idea with a positive phrase:

- *ça rentre par une oreille et ça ressort par l'autre...*